# Getting the turn based games in which a player is participating

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios6, game-center

I am trying to pull the turn based games in which a player is participating in order to populate my tableView.

This is my function to pull their games:

```
- (void) loadMatchDataWithArray:(NSMutableArray*)currentGames Flag:(bool*)returned
{
    NSMutableArray* __block blockGames = currentGames;
    bool* __block blockReturn = returned;

    [GKTurnBasedMatch loadMatchesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *matches, NSError *error)
     {
         if (matches)
         {
             for (int i = 0; i < matches.count; i++)
             {
                 [(GKTurnBasedMatch*)matches[i] loadMatchDataWithCompletionHandler: ^(NSData *matchData, NSError *error)
                  {
                      int size = [matchData length];
                      if (size != 0)
                      {
                          Game* game = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:matchData];
                          [blockGames addObject:game];
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          Game* game = [[Game alloc] init];
                          [blockGames addObject:game];
                          game.activePlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
                      }
                      *blockReturn = true;
                  }];
             }
         }
         else
         {
             *blockReturn = true;
         }
     }];
}
```

And this is where I call it:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [[self tableView]
    setBackgroundView:[[UIImageView alloc]
    initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"iPhoneBackground-568h"]]];

    bool* returned = false;
    [[GKMatchHelper sharedInstance] loadMatchDataWithArray:currentGames Flag:returned];
    while (!returned);
    [self.tableView reloadData];

    // Uncomment the following line to preserve selection between presentations.
    // self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;

    // Uncomment the following line to display an Edit button in the navigation bar for this view controller.
    // self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = self.editButtonItem;
}
```

Sadly, this is just giving me a blank black screen and never returns. Is there a way that I can detect when my block comes back and display a loading spinner until then, at which point I would reload the table?

EDIT:
I have revised my code and brought the function inside my MainMenuViewController, and now it builds but never displays the data.

```
- (void) loadMatchData
{
    NSMutableArray* __block blockGames = currentGames;
    MainMenuViewController* __weakSelf = self;

    [GKTurnBasedMatch loadMatchesWithCompletionHandler:^(NSArray *matches, NSError *error)
     {
         if (matches)
         {
             for (int i = 0; i < matches.count; i++)
             {
                 [(GKTurnBasedMatch*)matches[i] loadMatchDataWithCompletionHandler: ^(NSData *matchData, NSError *error)
                  {
                      int size = [matchData length];
                      if (size != 0)
                      {
                          Game* game = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData:matchData];
                          [blockGames addObject:game];
                      }
                      else
                      {
                          Game* game = [[Game alloc] init];
                          [blockGames addObject:game];
                          game.activePlayer = [GKLocalPlayer localPlayer];
                      }
                      [__weakSelf.tableView reloadData];
                  }];
             }
         }
         [__weakSelf.tableView reloadData];
     }];
    [__weakSelf.tableView reloadData];
}
```

And now in my ViewDidLoad I just call:

```
[self loadMatchData];
```

Comment: First off your missing the file extension on `iPhoneBackground-568h`

Comment: It's unnecessary - it's a PNG.

Comment: Are you sure? I might test that theory. Not that it makes a difference if it isn't required. Good to know for future reference though.

Comment: I have verified that it works separately.

Comment: Game center invitations are not working this days, I dont know what´s going on with game center SandBox server. I hope that your issue it is coming becuase of that.

Answer (score 0):

Oh dear. Do NOT halt the program execution with "while" loops!
Why not simply call `[self.tableView reloadData]` at the end of your block?

So,

1. Remove the last 2 lines in the `viewDidLoad` method
2. Replace `*blockReturn = true;` with `[self.tableView reloadData]` (you might need to keep a weak reference to 'self' to avoid retain cycles)
3. Never ever use `while (this and that)` to wait for an operation to complete. A non-responsive UI is bad and it will cause the users to abandon your app.

Comment: Hmm. I tried doing what you said, and it builds and doesn't crash, but never displays the data. I am editing the original post with the new version.

Comment: Delete this line `[__weakSelf.tableView reloadData];` in the `for` loop. Put a breakpoint on the second occurrence of this line and make sure `blockGames` contains data.